# ZXingScannerView.java NoSuchMethod in me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.onPreviewFrame

Tags: android, zxing

I am using a [barcode scanner library](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) and get the following error:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
>   No interface method sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
>          at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder.foundPatternDiagonal(FinderPatternFinder.java)
>          at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder.centerFromEnd(FinderPatternFinder.java)
>          at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.Detector.calculateModuleSize(Detector.java)
>          at com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader.decode(QRCodeReader.java)
>          at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.decodeInternal(MultiFormatReader.java)
>          at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.decode(MultiFormatReader.java)
>          at me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.onPreviewFrame(ZXingScannerView.java)
>          at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage + 1591(Camera.java:1591)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop + 168(Looper.java:168)
>          at android.os.HandlerThread.run + 61(HandlerThread.java:61)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please post also your code, where the error happens. The error alone is not enough

Comment: Use the basic code from the library followed in the [link](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner). This happening in the inside library